# Android get response from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

How i can get response from my AsyncTask class? 
i can use `onPostExecute` method. But is the way that when i call `execute()` method after this take response?
i tryed to pass result using property of async class, but it doesn't work.
How i can to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an asynctask that means you need to run something in a seperate thread because it is either a time consuming task or a network operation. That means you must use onPostExecute to do whatever you need to do with the result you get there

Comment: ah ok, so i need to do all my logics in the `onPostExecute`?